# Making a profile in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I'm a java developer trying to learn how to go about making a profile (for the user that is logged in and for other users which the logged in user can see) for react native and I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is. My instinct would be to make a profile object with fields for description, name, etc but it seems like this is not the ideal way to go about it in react. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if i understood good your question,
what i would do when i would want to create profile screen?

1. First i would think about some state managment like redux to get
   state by other screens/components
2. async storage for saving lets say token if user is logged in, by
   redux reducer i could initiate variable like this:

> isLogged: false

this variable would change every time when user would be logged in.
You could do a model for user with properties which it has, but when you fetch it from some API in JSON then its not necessary
Then how i would write the profile screen:

```
const ProfileScreen = props => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.users.user);
  const fetchUser = useSelector(state => state.users.fetchUser);
  const UserId = props.navigation.getParam('id');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await dispatch(usersActions.fetchUserData(UserId));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      }
    };
    loadUser();
  }, [UserId]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Name: {fetchUser.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Explanation:

- variable user - fetching state from redux reducer so its info about
  user logged in, if you want later to check if fetcheduser === user
  then you show edit button etc.
- variable fetchUser - its user who we want to see on profile page
- variable UserId we get from props of parent with navigation
- then we use useEffect to fire on start and when userId is changing,
  method fetchUserData is fetching data for user and then saving in to
  the state in redux then we can get his user name etc.

in render method we just show user details

if you want to check if user is logged in to show some notification then you could do something like this by render:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {isLogged && <Text> user is logged in show him something</Text>}
</View>
```